# Why there's no bind().to() functions in Google Dagger 2?

Tags: dependency-injection, guice, dagger-2

I found the bind().to() is very handy and clear in Google Guice. I think the combination of @Provides and provider functions in Dagger 2 are a bit more heavy. Why Dagger 2 doesn't support such sugar?

Answer (score 3):

Dagger is a *compile-time annotation processor*: It doesn't actually *run* your code while generating its interface implementations, and (through [`javax.annotation.processing.Processor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/Processor.html)) doesn't even have *access* to your method implementations in either a navigable (abstract syntax tree) or runnable state. It can only see class elements (methods and fields), with their annotations, and that is necessarily true so that Dagger can generate implementations like `DaggerYourComponent`.

Guice, by contrast, is entirely a runtime/reflective framework, and runs your `bind` statements (including any conditionals, loops, module subclasses) each time you create an Injector. New instances are created reflectively, and Guice will scan each class at runtime to determine its dependencies. This gives you much more flexibility with how to call `bind`, but much slower performance on memory- and processing-constrained environments, notably in environments like Android where [reflection is especially slow](http://blog.nimbledroid.com/2016/02/23/slow-Android-reflection.html).

In short, the switch to compile-time code generation limits how and where you can express bindings, but in trade you can avoid reflection entirely and gain signficant performance improvements.

Comment: Hi @Jeff Thanks so much for you explain! I just have a question that: is it possible for Dagger 2 to have the bind().to() syntax sugar while it does the compile time code generation trick? I just think the @ Provides and manually new some implementation instance is a bit more heavy than bind().to().

Comment: That would only work if you could _compile_ the code containing your modules, _run_ those modules in order to generate bindings for Dagger's generated code, and then compile that code to form your application. The problem is that your code often can't fully compile until Dagger is done: There'd be no definition of DaggerYourComponent, so compilation would fail. Given the need for very specific project setup, I think your suggestion is unlikely to gain traction. Alternative: Write a tool that implements Guice-style runnable modules and code-gens Dagger Modules for you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Well technically the modules allow this.

```
@Module
public class MyModule {
    @Provides
    MyInterface myInterface(MyClass myClass) { // <-- equivalent of `bind().to()`
        return myClass;
    }
}
```

Another option:

```
@Module
public abstract class MyModule {
    @Binds // <-- equivalent of `bind().to()`
    abstract MyInterface myInterface(MyClass myClass);
}
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure how this answers the question, as the question mentions `@Provides`.

Comment: @JeffBowman `@Binds` seems to be the direct answer to "why there's no bind().to() functions in Google Dagger 2"

Comment: @Tavian Is it, though? It seems like it answers "what should I use instead" or "how close can supported Dagger syntax get", not why the Guice method calls are unsupported or impossible.